# NDSolve works fine on a coarse grid but fails on finer grid

Tags: differential-equations

I was working on build a ionosphere model by dynamic equation and ion continuity equation:

$n m(\partial W/\partial t+W\partial W/\partial z)=-\partial(n k_B T)/\partial z-n m g-\nu n W $

$\partial n/\partial t = Product-Loss-\partial(n W)/\partial z$

To solve this equation, first prepare the `Method` (copied from other post, I forget the origin, too many people use this):

```
mol[n : _Integer | {_Integer ..}, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := 
{"MethodOfLines", 
"TemporalVariable"->t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" ->{"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints"->n, 
"MinPoints"->n, "DifferenceOrder"->o}}
```

If I solve the equation with a coarse grid:

```
kB = 1.380649*10^(-23);
mp = 1.6726231*10^(-27);
pf = Interpolation[{{100, 4.6}, {120,7.5}, {150, 7.6}, {180, 5.6}, {200, 4.3}, {250, 1.3}},
 InterpolationOrder -> 3];
(testmodel0014ionsW00301 = 
NDSolve[{

 (44 mp*CO2P[h, t] + mp*0.001)*(D[W[h, t], t] + W[h, t]*D[W[h, t], h]/1000)
  == -(kB*1.5*D[(CO2P[h, t])*(h^2/20), h]/1000)
     - (44 mp*CO2P[h, t] + mp*0.001)*9
     - W[h, t]*(44 mp*CO2P[h, t]*(5*10^(-10)*Exp[48 - 0.16 h])+ 10^(-24)),

 D[CO2P[h, t], t] == 0.0001*10^pf[h] - 1.*10^(-16 + 6) CO2P[h, t]*Exp[30 - 0.05 h]
   - D[CO2P[h, t]*W[h, t], h]/1000,
 
 W[h, 0] == 0.,
 CO2P[h, 0] == 0.,    
 W[100, t] == 0.,
 CO2P[100, t] == 0.

 }, {W, CO2P}, {h, 100, 250}, {t, 0, 2000}, Method -> mol[33]]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

`NDSolve` works fine and return a  reasonable solution, for example, `CO2P[h,t]` looks like:

[image]

However if I use a finer grid, change `Method -> mol[33]` to `Method -> mol[55]`, `NDSolve` breaks after few seconds. Why would this happen? Shouldn't we expect a finer grid to produce better result?

Comment: "Pseudospectral" uses a coarse grid. Have you tried the default method?

Comment: strangely the default method also fails and throws "1/0" and "0.` ComplexInfinity" error..@NamNguyen

Comment: How does `NDSolve` "break"?  Could you give values for `mp`,  `kB`, and any other parameters needed to make this run?

Comment: Ohh..sorry I forget to add the parameters..now I have edited the question and add values for `mp` and `kB`: `kB = 1.380649*10^(-23);mp = 1.6726231*10^(-27);`. @ChrisK